# Start counting bars number when the condition is met and add the exceptions to the count as well

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

When the conditions are met, I want to count the bars number, but also add exceptions.
For example, I want to count 11 days in a row to see if there is 9 days up during this period, and if one day(let's say today) is down but the close price are less or equal to 1% than yesterday (means yesterday is up day, not previous up day), then count this day is a up day too.

For example, let's say day1 is up day, here is 11days in a row, and there is 3 days down (day3, day5, day6), but day3's close price are less or equal to 1% than yesterday (means day2 and day2 is up day), and day2 is up day, so day3 is a up day too, which mean is it will met the condition this time.(9 days up in 11days)

```
day1  day2  day3   day4  day5   day6   day7   day8  day9  day10  day11
10    11    10.5   10.8    9     8      12     17    18     19    20
up    up    down    up    down  down    up     up    up     up    up
```

And in a case like this, the condition is not valid, day3' close price are less or equal to 1% than yesterday(day2), but yesterday(day2) are not up day, which mean the condition are not met this time.(8 days up in 11days this time)

```
day1  day2  day3   day4  day5   day6  day7  day8  day9  day10  day11
10     9     8.5   10.8    8     9     12    17    18    19     20
up    down   down   up    down   up    up    up    up    up     up
```

This is my code:

```
//@version=5

indicator("Green bars", overlay = true, max_labels_count = 500)

barsBack = input.int(11)

var float[] green_bar_array = array.new_float()

if close > close[1] or ((close/close[1])-1) * 100 <= 1
    array.push(green_bar_array, close)

if array.size(green_bar_array) > barsBack
    array.shift(green_bar_array)

bool updaygreen = false
int green_count = 0

if array.size(green_bar_array) == barsBack
    for i = 1 to barsBack - 1
        if array.get(green_bar_array, i) >= array.get(green_bar_array, i - 1)
            green_count += 1
    if green_count >= 9
        updaygreen := true

plotshape(updaygreen, location=location.belowbar, color=#00b543, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, transp=55)
```

But the result are not correct... what am I missing?
Please help me, thanks!

EDIT:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Count Bar Color", overlay = true, max_labels_count = 500)

var int     barsBack        = input.int(11, 'Number of bars lookback', 0)

var int[]   greenBars       = array.new_int(barsBack, 0)
var int[]   redBars         = array.new_int(barsBack, 0)
var int     greenBarCount   = 0
var int     redBarCount     = 0

direction = ta.change(close) // red or green ?

if barstate.isconfirmed
    if direction > 0
        array.push(greenBars, 1) 
        array.push(redBars,   0)
    else if direction < 0 
        array.push(greenBars, 0) 
        array.push(redBars,   1)

    if direction != 0 
        array.shift(greenBars) 
        array.shift(redBars)

    greenBarCount := array.sum(greenBars)
    redBarCount   := array.sum(redBars)

upday = greenBarCount >= 9

plotshape(upday, location=location.belowbar, color=#00b543, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, transp=55)
```

Changed my code to this now, but still don't know how to add "close price are less or equal to 1% than yesterday(yesterday is up day, not previous up day)" into it...

Comment: 1% or 10%? In your first example, 10.5/11 = 0.9545.

Comment: Also, if it's a down day, `close/close[1]` will be less than `1` , therefore `((close/close[1])-1) * 100` is negative, so `((close/close[1])-1) * 100 <= 1` will always return true.

Comment: It's 1%, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it. Please try it and leave feedback.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Count Bar Color")
len = input(11)
thres = input(9)
pct = input(1.0)
up = close >= close[1]
dn = close < close[1]
valid = up or (up[1] and dn and ta.roc(close, 1)>-pct)
count = math.sum(valid?1:0, len)
plot(count, color=count>=thres?color.yellow:color.blue, style=plot.style_columns)
hline(thres)
```

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for the help and reply. I did some tests and found that some results were correct and some were not. For example, [this one](https://imgur.com/9VHhHYT), this is for the period from July 16 to July 27 last year on BTC/USDT chart. This period are not valid, because there is 3 days down during this period, and on these down day, their closing price are not less or equal to 1% than yesterday closing price (when yesterday is up day), it should be triggered on the 28th, 29th and 30th.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. I think the result is correct. There are 12 days from July 16th to July 27th, not 11 days. The ruler didn't count the first red bar as 1 bar (you can tell by only measuring one bar, the ruler will display "0 bars").

Comment: Oh my goodness! I've made a terrible mistake...I checked my chart again and all the results are correct! Thank you so much for your help and patience, I appreciate it!